# At least one Product & Price > 0 required when Opportunity Stage changed to Closed Won

Tags: opportunity, validation, validation-rule

The business requirement is:

At least one `Product && Price > 0` when changing the Opportunity Stage to `Closed Won`.

I able to write validation that check if the Opportunity has at least one Product added but I could not able to figured how would I do for price `Price > 0`

The below VR checks at least one product is added, How would I add Price > 0?

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
  HasOpportunityLineItem = FALSE
)
```

Comment: `Amount > 0`...?

Comment: silly me... i was trying with wrong field name that's why i could not able to find the right field name

Comment: if i add `HasOpportunityLineItem = FALSE && Amount > 0` the validation does not fire even though I have no products and if I removed the `&& Amount >0` then the validations fire correctly.

Comment: Sorry, you just got yourself confused between && and ||. I'll illustrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won") &&
(!HasOpportunityLineItem || Amount <= 0)
```

We want the validation rule to reach "true" when an error should occur. This means that we need to use "or" to indicate that either condition can cause the error. The above rule should trigger properly.

Comment: 1+ Thanks but I see the problem now, I can not delete the related list item in  `Products (Standard Price Book)`  when I do try to delete i'm getting validation rule error message, looks like its firing the VR when deleting, its odd.

Comment: @NickKahn performing a delete on line items causes an update on the opportunity by virtue of a rollup update. You might also need to use ISCHANGED of you're interested in just when it changes.

Comment: on which field should I use ISCHANGED? I'm sorry confused now.

Comment: @NickKahn I'm thinking something like: `ISCHANGED(StageName) && ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won") && (!HasOpportunityLineItem || Amount <= 0)`. Does that help?

Comment: `ISCHANGED(StageName....` fixed the problem of deleting but now after I delete the product when I try to save the Opportunity record without Product I able to save without getting any validation error... hmmm

Comment: @NickKahn Thinking about it, if you're concerned about deletions, I think we're now up to: `(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won") && (Amount <= 0 || !HasOpportunityLineItem) && !PRIORVALUE(HasOpportunityLineItem))`.